# "This is what I understand" or "This is how I understand it", etc

Tags: grammaticality, writing-style, speech

Which one of the following statements is correct or do all of them make sense?

1. > System A works independently and does not affect System B. This is what I understand.
2. > System A works independently and does not affect System B. This is how I understand it.
3. > System A works independently and does not affect System B. This is my understanding.

Comment: *What I understand* (the fact I know) means something quite different from *how I understand it* (the way in which I understand it).

Comment: "How I understand it" is a rather complicated phrase with several possible meanings, depending on context.

Answer (score 1):

All three are correct and make sense, but it would probably be better to say

> My understanding is that System A works independently and does not affect System B.